# How to add dictionary path in search path for hunspell on windows?

Tags: makefile, cygwin, configure, hunspell

The following link states the cygwin method to install hunspell on windows: https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell

The executable installed has unix like dictionary search path as follows:

> $ hunspell.exe -D
>
> SEARCH PATH:
>   .::/usr/share/hunspell:/usr/share/myspell:/usr/share/myspell/dicts:/Library/Spelling:/home/nchaturv/.openoffice.org/3/user/wordbook:/home/nchaturv/.openoffice.org2/user/wordbook:/home/nchaturv/.openoffice.org2.0/user/wordbook:/home/nchaturv/Library/Spelling:/opt/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo
>
> AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):

The paths above are unix paths and not windows paths. And there is no default dictionary So, I have to add the dictionary en_US.dic to the search path.

**Is there a way to add some path to the search lib path while configuring or building?** I tried using the following but it did not work out.

> export LDFLAGS='-L/home/foo/sw/lib/'

I do not get the dictionary not present error if I have the en_US.dic file in the folder I am running hunspell from. But, I would like to add a path to the search path and place the dictionary and affix files there.

Comment: LDFLAGS is only usefult for compilation of a program. The cygwin Hunspell program has the dictionary under `/usr/share/myspell`

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the source code at https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/blob/master/src/tools/hunspell.cxx#L2040-L2072, you can use `DICPATH` to add a directory at runtime.  Some of the directories are derived from `HOME`, but with hard-coded suffixes.  There doesn't seem to be any means of changing any of the other directories at configure- or buildtime, save for patching the source code.